# Swift blank app

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift4

I want to learn SpriteKit and am following this tutorial, https://www.raywenderlich.com/187645/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners-2 
I have copied and pasted the same code from the tutorial into GameScene.swift as well as moved the picture of the ninja into Assets.xcassets
However, when I get two errors,

Before I run it I get

> Forced cast of `SkView` to same type has no effect

After I run it I also get

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x7ffeed594fa8

When I run it, the app is simply blank... The app should show FPS count and NodeCount?
Here's my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

All of this code is in GameScene.swift
If someone could please help me that would be great!
UPDATE: I am using Swift 4

Comment: you might be missing a Main.storyboard ?

Comment: No? I have it..?

Comment: I think you have an infinite loop. You should not be creating a new `GameScene` inside `GameScene.didMove`.

Comment: PSE: FYI, your behavior is somewhat suspicious, and is being [discussed in meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369252/522444).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have an infinite recursion there. Note that you already have a `GameScene` instance but in the `didMove` you are creating *another* `GameScene` which you are presenting again which again is presented in the view and `didMove` is called again and so on. I think your code should look something like this:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
   self.size = view.bounds.size
   view.showsFPS = true
   view.showsNodeCount = true
   view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
   self.scaleMode = .resizeFill
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you were right about suspicious behavior. I'm guessing this question and the others will soon be gone